# C++ - shared_ptr<vector<T>> vs. vector<shared_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, stdvector

I see a lot of cases where people use `vector<shared_ptr<T>>`. When and why would you use `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` instead? For me, the latter seems more efficient both in performance and memory-usage. Is it wrong to share a single vector of objects across the application?

Thanks

Comment: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is a vector of shared pointers, `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` is a shared pointer to a vector. Quite different.

Comment: Also, don't look at the new smart pointers as *pointers*, instead you should look at it from an ownership perspective. Can the pointer be owned by only a single "user" at a time, or by multiple "users" simultaneously?

Comment: Is there ever any case where one would use `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`?  (This type presupposes a dynamically allocated `std::vector`, and cases where one would dynamically allocate an `std::vector` are exceedingly rare.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: When you're trying to represent a tree in memory perhaps? Although I would personally just go ahead and use `class Node : public std::vector<Node>`, the UB in the standard be damned.

Comment: @Mehrdad Except that that doesn't compile, at least not with g++.  (I'm assuming, of course, the usual g++ options, including `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS`.  And of course, it won't compile with some future version of the standard; the goal of concepts was to make this an error requiring a diagnostic.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: By "that" do you mean `shared_ptr<vector<T> >`  or do you mean my tree class definition (which had no `shared_ptr`)?

Comment: @JamesKanze: "Is there ever any case where one would use `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`?" - [here's an example](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=J1HMLyxqJfgC&pg=PT923&lpg=PT923&dq=%22std::shared_ptr%3Cstd::vector%3C%22&source=bl&ots=FIODZmZdco&sig=lBAqQd2WTeTrzvhKaMnNhafwi1E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oG4yVInuOsT98QWFv4LwCQ&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22std%3A%3Ashared_ptr%3Cstd%3A%3Avector%3C%22&f=false) from C++ Primer by Stanley Lipman, Josée Lajoie, and Barbara Moo.  Lots of SO questions about them too.

Comment: @Mehrdad Your tree class definition.  In general, I think you'd have an `std::vector<Node*>`, but avoiding the need for a complete definition could be a potential exception to the rule.

Comment: @TonyD Your link leads me to a message that I can't view the page, so I can't comment about it.  But from what I've seen concerning the questions about them here, most of the time, it seems to be a problem of someone trying to program like they did in Java; with the correct answer being to drop the pointer entirely.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ahhh well, the book had a constructor `QueryResult(string s, shared_ptr<set<line_no>, shared_ptr<vector<string>>)` and copied the ptrs into member vars.  Separately, I agree it's liable to be misunderstood, especially by those coming from Java/C#, but more generally all the legitimate reasons for wanting a `shared_ptr` for a container aren't much different than for a single data - the container's lifetime needs to be decoupled and ownership decentralised....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This use: `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` will allow you to pass instances of type `T` from this vector to some other parts of code without fear that they will not be freed. Even if your vector will no longer exist.

`shared_ptr<vector<T>>` on the other hand protects only vector, its elements of type `T` are not protected against memory leaks. I assume here that `T` is of pointer type, if `T` is non-pointer, then of course you don't have a problem with making memory leak here. Well someone could make `T = shared_ptr<T>` actually.

Its actually more common to use `vector<shared_ptr<T>>`, I don't really remember using `shared_ptr<vector<T>>`.

The point is to never keep, in your code, bare pointers to allocated memory, always keep them in some kind of smart pointer. Its perfectly fine if you implement your own allocate/deallocate mechanism, i.e.. using RAII.

Comment: The last sentence is utter nonsense.  A lot depends on the application, but in most applications which use dynamic memory, I would expect that most pointers are for navigation, and should be raw pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze I changed last sentence, I meant pointer to allocated memory

Comment: But that doesn't change anything.  In a lot of applications (most of the ones I've worked on, anyway), the reason for dynamic allocation is that the object in question has a lifetime determined by program logic.  Which means that smart pointers aren't appropriate.

Comment: Not sure if I understand - you say "smart pointers aren't appropriate" for "dynamic allocation" ?

Comment: "never keep, in your code, bare pointers to allocated memory" is over-the-top given reasonable operations like tracking positions within a buffer using a pointer, but it's equally obviously intended to refer to the "owning" pointer that ought to be used to deallocate the memory.  Sure dynamic allocation implies lifetime decoupled from allocating scope, but you can return a smart pointer and let it bubble up to whatever scope is maintaining ongoing ownership with relatively little overhead; some people consider it good style, and FWIW I don't see any particular problem either way.

Comment: I should name it `pointer to allocated memory that if lost will cause leak and if not safely managed should cause insomnia`.